# Combing separate array data to output separately

Tags: php, arrays

The function below works OK, it assigns data from two sources to output in two separate rows.

I want to output both data (separated with a space) on a single row instead of two separate rows.

Have tried comma separated and plus but just get blanks, I do not want to merge anything just to have both data_1 and data_2 appear separately on same row .

This must be a simple task but have been at it for a couple of days..

Any tips

```
public function assignArray()
{

     $assigned_array=array();

     $assigned_array['data_1'.$this->user_id]='Title_Row1';

     $assigned_array['data_2'.$this->user_id]='Title_Row2';

    return $assigned_array;

}
```

Comment: You aren't giving enough information. This is just giving a function. Where are you printing this?

Comment: Do you want to assign the array values on one single line?

Comment: _data_1 and data_2 appear separately on same row_ Same row of the ARRAY or the same row of the HTML output? Show us what you do with this function NOW and what it outputs. THEN show us the new output you want

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. The function dictates something called $table_values, the $table_values are displayed as a report with this

Comment: <?php  foreach($date_list as $val) { ?>
      <td class="<?php echo $this->Dateformat()->getreportColor($tables_values[$val],$key3); ?>">
      <?php echo $tables_values[$val];    ?>
      </td>

Comment: This displays a table of date columns, for each user_id two rows appear , a row with Title_Row1 with data_1 and below that a second row with Title_Row1 appears with data_2. I would like to only have one row appear (does not matter what Row Title) but with data_1 and data_2 appearing. It is the output that I would like to change, from $table_values. I do not know exactly the mechanism, only that the assigned_array dictates what the $table_values are. Sorry but this is from a project that I did not originally write and am learning as I go along.